# Dropbox Android SDK refuses to link multiple accounts

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm working on an android application that allows user to link multiple dropbox accounts (personal, business from one or more accounts).

I'm using Dropbox Core SDK for Android v 1.6.3.

From time to time I'm experiencing the problem when it's not possible to link the second dropbox account if I link the first one through "Use different account" -> chrome login and then try to immediately link the second one through the dropbox app directly (or through web browser again, probably). Dropbox SDK simply never returns auth tokens to my app.

I've made a small investigation on internals of the process and it appears that the problem is current version's of android dropbox application fault.

Basically, I can see that SDK internally generates a random nonce value used to authenticate callbacks from the dropbox app. And this value is somehow gets cached in the dropbox app: when I try to link the second account my app receives valid credentials from the dropbox app but the nonce is not correct - it's the one from the previous link process, so the SDK discards credentials.

I can also see that when I try to link the second account through the "Use different account" the dropbox app fires VIEW intent with wrong nonce value the URL. So seems like this is the dropbox app's fault rather than some system behavior.

The issue is reproducible for me on android 4.4 and 5.0.

Maybe someone from the dropbox team can advise me something? I'm ready to provide additional details if they are required.

Comment: This is a known issue that can occur when the app authorization prompt in the Dropbox app doesn't get properly dismissed or updated on subsequent requests. We're working on it.

Comment: Greg, good to know. Do you have a timeline for the fix? I can't say it's super severe but very annoying!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a timeline right now.